# Perform Cubic Spline Interpolation in an image Python

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation, spline

Let's say, I have frames (50) of images (656, 875, 3) - (W x H x C). So, the final input is an array with shape (50, 656, 875, 3). If my input points have dimensions (24, 2) - (x, y), how would I perform cubic spline interpolation in every frame?

To clarify what I want to achieve, I have topographic maps of brain like the above image [A topographic map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IW78.jpg), which has been created from EGG. On this map, there are some points under the brain where the sensors of the EGG have been placed like the second one image [Second topographic map with sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWHxq.png). Every frame is a frequency and I want to produce an EGG cube using the cubic spline interpolation.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish. You have a series of 24 (x,y) coordinates. Do you want to fit a spline through those points? How does this relate to the 50 frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, as cubic splines could be used for several things in image processing:

- Image resizing (Interpolation between pixels)
- Video resampling (Interpolation between frames)
- Curve fitting (Interpolation between points)

Since you have a series of points, I'm assuming you want to do the curve fitting. Take a look at the [SciPy cubic spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) docs. After you have the polynomial, you could step through the breakpoints and plot each pixel to the frame.

Edit:
If you want to do a 3D cubic spline (forming a 3D surface), it will require the points to be in the same plane, and the height of the surface represent magnitude at each point. There are some examples of this using scipy.interpolate.Rbf in [StackEchange: Spline Interpolation in 3D in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040382/spline-interpolation-in-3d-in-python).
If your points are not in the same plane, you could forgo the cubic spline and use a gaussian blur from the pillow library.