# How to linear interpolate the x, y, and z between two points?

Tags: python, linear-interpolation

Lets say at start time 0s I have point_1(10,20,35) and  at end time 10s I have point_2(20,40,50)

How would I go about using linear interpolation to find where a point would be at time 5s?

I want to do this by hand without using any python libraries. I'm trying to understand how to use linear interpolation with an x,y, and z plane.

I know i would start with this

```
start_time = 0
start_x = 10
start_y = 20
start_z = 35

end_time = 10
end_x = 20
end_y = 40
end_z = 50

# I want the point at time 5s
time = 5
def interpolate():
    pass
```

Comment: An interpolation generally requires a parameter to tell you which point between the endpoints is desired.

Comment: If all i have is that I want it at time 5 seconds is it possible to solve?

Comment: Yes it's possible to solve, I'm just pointing out that your function `interpolate` is missing a parameter.

Comment: There are libraries that can do this for you, explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836067/interpolate-3d-volume-with-numpy-and-or-scipy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to interpolate between `x1` and `x2` is `(1 - t) * x1 + t * x2` where `t` ranges from 0 to 1. We need to put `t` into this range first:

```py
def interpolate(v1, v2, start_time, end_time, t):
    t = (t - start_time) / (end_time - start_time)
    return tuple((1 - t) * x1 + t * x2 for x1, x2 in zip(v1, v2))
```

Example:

```py
>>> interpolate((10, 20, 35), (20, 40, 50), 0, 10, 5)
(15.0, 30.0, 42.5)
```

Comment: Where did you find that formula `(1 - t) * x1 + t * x2`

the interpolate function I found was not like that

Comment: Any basic textbook will give this formula, or an equivalent one like `x1 + t * (x2 - x1)`. See Wikipedia for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Programming_language_support

Comment: Ok yeah you're right I was looking at the other equivalent.