# 4D Density Plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, 3d

I am looking to plot some density maps from some grid-like data:

```
X,Y,Z = np.mgrids[-5:5:50j, -5:5:50j, -5:5:50j]
rho = np.random.rand(50,50,50) #for the sake of argument
```

I am interested in producing an interpolated density plot as shown below, from Mathematica [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica), using Python.

Is there any solution in Matplotlib or another plotting suite for this sort of plot?

To be clear, I do not want a scatterplot of coloured points, which is not suitable the plot I am trying to make. I would like a 3D interpolated density plot, as shown below.

[image: 4D Density Plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a 4d plot with matplotlib using arbitrary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995610/how-to-make-a-4d-plot-with-matplotlib-using-arbitrary-data)

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately, these do not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

### Plotly

Plotly Approach from https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/ uses np.mgrid

```python
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-8:8:40j, -8:8:40j, -8:8:40j]
values = np.sin(X*Y*Z) / (X*Y*Z)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=0.1,
    isomax=0.8,
    opacity=0.1, # needs to be small to see through all surfaces
    surface_count=17, # needs to be a large number for good volume rendering
    ))
fig.show()
```

[image: screenshot of interactive output]

### Pyvista

Volume Rendering example:
https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/volume.html#sphx-glr-examples-02-plot-volume-py

3D-interpolation code you might need with pyvista:
[interpolate 3D volume with numpy and or scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836067/interpolate-3d-volume-with-numpy-and-or-scipy)